# Grouping Set of Rows and Assigning/Updating Unique number to each set in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, dense-rank

I've a requirement of grouping nth(configurable) rows (bags) by some criteria (Zone) and then assign/update each group a unique identifier which should never repeat for any other group in that table (Shipping_Bags).

Currently I have few empty fields(UserDef1/2..) in my table where I can update/populate the UniqueGroupID value. 
Currently my data looks like:
Bags which are already delivered/shipped have UniqueGroupID, in similar fashion we need to update UniqueGroupID for future deliveries, so by filtering UniqueGroupID, system can find the associated 4 bags with it. Hence the requirement of uniqueness.

```
Select BagId, Zone, UserDef1, ShipDate from Shipping_Bag;

BagID     Zone           UserDef1     ShipDate
1         East              1        24/04/2018
2         East              1        24/04/2018
3         East              1        24/04/2018
4         East              1        24/04/2018
5         East              2        24/04/2018
6         East              2        24/04/2018
7         East              2        24/04/2018
8         West              3        25/04/2018
9         West              3        25/04/2018
10        North             4        25/04/2018
11        North             0        27/04/2018
12        North             0        27/04/2018
13        North             0        27/04/2018
14        North             0        27/04/2018
15        Central           0        27/04/2018
16        Central           0        27/04/2018
17        Central           0        27/04/2018
18        Central           0        27/04/2018
19        Central           0        27/04/2018
```

I want to achieve below output (Grouping 4 bags per Zone):

```
Select BagId, Zone, UserDef1 as UniqueGroupID, ShipDate from Shipping_Bag;

   BagID     Zone      UniqueGroupID     ShipDate
    1         East              1        24/04/2018
    2         East              1        24/04/2018
    3         East              1        24/04/2018
    4         East              1        24/04/2018
    5         East              2        24/04/2018
    6         East              2        24/04/2018
    7         East              2        24/04/2018
    8         West              3        25/04/2018
    9         West              3        25/04/2018
    10        North             4        25/04/2018
    11        North             5        27/04/2018
    12        North             5        27/04/2018
    13        North             5        27/04/2018
    14        North             5        27/04/2018
    15        Central           6        27/04/2018
    16        Central           6        27/04/2018
    17        Central           6        27/04/2018
    18        Central           6        27/04/2018
    19        Central           7        27/04/2018
```

I tried and got the output:

select
BagID, Zone,
    --calculate the group number for every 4 bags, increment 1
    ceiling(row_number() over(partition by zone order by BagID) / 4.0) UniqueGroupID
from shipping_bag

Challenge here is; I need to come up with NextUp Number logic to update/populate the UniqueGroupID so it must never repeat for any BagID in future.

Comment: If that's your expected output, what does your original data look like?  We can't tell you how to get the results you want if we don't know what it looked like before. Post your sample as well as your expected results: [Forum Etiquette: How to post data for a T-SQL question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets you the results you're after for the sample data we have:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE Shipping (BagID int, [Zone] varchar(5), UserDef int);

INSERT INTO Shipping
VALUES (1,'East',0),
       (2,'East',0),
       (3,'East',0),
       (4,'East',0),
       (5,'East',0),
       (6,'East',0),
       (7,'East',0),
       (8,'West',0),
       (9,'West',0),
       (10,'North',0),
       (11,'North',0),
       (12,'North',0),
       (13,'North',0),
       (14,'North',0);
GO
DECLARE @BagSize int = 4;

WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY BagID) AS RN,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Zone] ORDER BY BagID) AS BagRN
    FROM Shipping)
SELECT BagID,
       [Zone],
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (RN - BagRN) + ((BagRN -1) / @BagSize)) AS UniqueGroupID
FROM RNs
ORDER BY BagID;

GO
DROP TABLE Shipping;
GO
```

*Edit: ok, maybe this works what what you need when you have already existing data:*

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE Shipping (BagID int, [Zone] varchar(5), UserDef int);

INSERT INTO Shipping
VALUES (1,'East',1),
       (2,'East',1),
       (3,'East',1),
       (4,'East',1),
       (5,'East',2),
       (6,'East',2),
       (7,'East',3),
       (8,'West',4),
       (9,'West',4),
       (10,'North',0),
       (11,'North',0),
       (12,'North',0),
       (13,'North',0),
       (14,'North',0);
GO
DECLARE @BagSize int = 4;

WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY BagID) AS RN,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Zone] ORDER BY BagID) AS BagRN,
           CASE UserDef WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS UserDefBit,
           MAX(UserDef) OVER () AS MaxUserDef
    FROM Shipping)
SELECT BagID,
       [Zone],
       CASE UserDef WHEN 0 THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY UserDefBit ORDER BY (RN - BagRN) + ((BagRN -1) / @BagSize)) + MaxUserDef
                    ELSE UserDef END AS UniqueGroupID
FROM RNs
ORDER BY BagID;

GO
DROP TABLE Shipping;
GO
```

*Note: I haven't tried this with the OP's new sample data as it isn't in the form of a `INSERT` statement (and thus not consumable). I made the effort with the original data, but I have not repeated the process for new data.*

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution but it doesn't work if I already have some BagIDs assigned with UniqueGroupID and also the requirement is UniqueGroupID should not be reused:

       (2,'East',0),
       (3,'East',0),
       (4,'East',0),
       (5,'East',0),
       (6,'East',0),
       (7,'East',0),
       (8,'West',0),
       (9,'West',0),
       (10,'North',0),
       (11,'North',0),
       (12,'North',0),
       (13,'North',0),
       (14,'North',0),
       (15,'South',1),
       (16,'South',1),
       (17,'South',1),
       (18,'South',1),
       (19,'South',2)

Comment: @AmanGarg this is why you need to include **representative** sample data. I can't provide a solution for data I don't know exists (this is why I said it works for the sample data we have). Please update your post to be representative of what you have and the expected results for it. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this time to put the use case with all the details possible. I cannot share the actual use case of the requirement but I am trying to match it by above example as much as possible. If you need more details, please feel free to ask, highly appreciate your help and patience.

Comment: Oh well it looks promising, I will implement it in my actual logic. Thank you so much Larnu!

Comment: @AmanGarg if the solution works, then please do mark it as so. Thanks.

Comment: When I tried the logic in Prod. it worked for present data in active table but we have one complication, We archive data from active table but would still need to keep the unique number generated for GroupID. I've the stored-procedure to generate next-up number, is it possible, if we can call that SP dynamically and assign a groupID to a set of 4 bags, by that way, GroupID will be unique even if we combine data from active and archive table and also currently we are scanning through entire table to get the MAX(UserDef), this can be resolved by using Next-Up generated number.

Comment: @AmanGarg get the value of the maximum from where ever you need to, and then store it to a variable instead (instead of using the `MAX` value in the table? You should, however, understand the code above that I've supplied enough to be able to make minor changes to it. You shouldn't be using code supplied by someone on the internet if you don't understand it; especially in the work place. :)

Comment: I achieved it by calling my Next-up Number generator SP and using the Output instead of Max(UserDef).
One thing which I didn't understand was Order By clause in Dense_Rank() which you used and yeah thanks for the help and suggestion. 
If I am using cooked logic from the internet I make sure I test it thoroughly before deploying.